# unable to open text file

Tags: input, fstream

I'm trying to get a program to open a file and read from it.  However, I can't seem to get it to open the file.  I've read several threads about this and I've seen the suggestion to make sure the file is in the same directory as my executable.  I don't know how to check if that's true.  The text file is saved in the same file as my program files, if that helps.  Can anyone give me some input?  Relevant code below.  Thanks!

```
std::ifstream myfile;
myfile.open("../ResInput.txt", ios::in);
 if(myfile.is_open()){ 
getline(myfile, stemp1);...
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `open()` call is trying to go up one directory to read the file as it's written right now. If you want the file opened in the same directory as your executable, remove the `../` in your `open()` call.

This is also assuming your OS accepts a forward slash as a directory separator. It would also be useful to know the error you are getting.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I was able to get some help with this live since I posted the question; it turns out the whole project was not saved correctly.